# Python - how to access class method variable from another class level

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Below you can see some code from DrawClass class. I want to read text from **entryConnection** variable in one of ActionClass methods(another class). How to access it? I were looking for answer on stackoverflow but didn't find any solution...

```
class DrawClass(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.DrawGUI=DrawClass

        def drawall(self):

            # MENU
            menuBar = Menu(okno)
            progMenu = Menu(menuBar, tearoff=0)
            menuBar.add_cascade(label="Program", menu=progMenu)
            progMenu.add_command(label="Konfiguracja", command=action.donothing)
            progMenu.add_separator()
            progMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=okno.quit)
            okno.config(menu=menuBar)


            #FRAME na wszystko związane z bazą
            databaseFrame = Frame(okno, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=5)
            databaseFrame.grid(sticky=NW)



            #FRAME na połączenie
            connectionFrame = Frame(databaseFrame, relief=RAISED, borderwidth=2, width=350, height=55)
            connectionFrame.grid(sticky=N)
            connectionFrame.grid_propagate(FALSE)


            buttonConnect = tkinter.Button(connectionFrame, text="Połącz z bazą", fg="RED").grid(row=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)
            labelConnection = tkinter.Label(connectionFrame, text="Status połączenia z bazą:").grid(row=1, sticky=W+E+N+S)
            entryConnection = tkinter.Entry(connectionFrame).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W+E+N+S)
```

Is it accessible through **init**? Or should I rebuild class totally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't got a class variable, or even an instance variable - you just have a local var. If you want to use it as an instance var, define it on self.

```
self.entryConnection = ...
```